# Calculating time length, through PHP or mySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

In my form users sumbit many events with individual times associated to each one.

e.g. For a Appendectomy the first event Event#1 began at 12:54:33pm and the last even Event#12 happened at 2:23:04pm.
So for the Appendectomy there was 12 events.

These events are placed in a seperate table with a foreign key to the event name (Appendectomy).

So if I wanted to calculate the amount of time would it be better to do it through the database or using PHP.

I am unsure because of these reasons:

**PHP:**

> The time formats are strings and I don't think you can subtract
>   strings
>
> The time formats are like this HH:MM:SS which may be complex
>   to split the strings and reconcatenate them later.

**MySQL:**

> > The time formats in the the column are actual times not strings
> >     Would
> >     have to use mysql joins and then find the total events for that
> >     procedure.  Which would be complex?
>
> Stored procedure?

I am still new to alot of this so I was wondering what your guidance would be on this matter?

Comment: Could you please provide the database layout to help us help you?

Comment: Thankyou here is a schema sorry for the delay http://i.imgur.com/0vzoT.png

Comment: My answer below is now changed to reflect your layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With SQL:

```
SELECT procedure_id, SUBTIME(events_max.start, events_min.start) AS duration
FROM procedure
JOIN ( SELECT procedure_id, SELECT MAX(time) AS start FROM procedure_events GROUP BY procedure_id ) AS events_max USING ( procedure_id )
JOIN ( SELECT procedure_id, SELECT MIN(time) AS start FROM procedure_events GROUP BY procedure_id ) AS events_min USING ( procedure_id )
GROUP BY procedure_id
```

Would give you the procedure IDs and duration of each procedure as given by the time difference between the start of the first event and the last event.